# Is there anything special to operate on vector in an OpenCL kernel?

Tags: vector, opencl

I have to optimize my OpenCL program. So I think I will have to use vectors operations provided by my GPU (a small 4 cores one) to do it.

I saw that its preferred vector width is 4 for char / short / int / floatn the types it can process.

I think I only have to call:

```
__kernel void mykernel(__global char4 *a,
                       __global char4 *b)
```

to use vectors operations but how OpenCL deals with 'a' if it's not a multiple of 4 ?

Thanks

Baptiste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean if a is not multiple of 4?

In the case you expose `a` and `b`are char4 types. Each of those types is a struct containing 4 char elements. Operations like `a[0].x` `a[0].y` `a[0].z` `a[0].w` are allowed.
But you will NEVER have a semi-structure in your kernel, aka a non-complete structure.

Given your question I suspect you try to say, "What if my host passes a non multiple of 4 char array". The problem is not there but in the type you use in your host side. Since you should NEVER use a type in the host side that does not match the one in the kernel.

(Are you using cl_char?)
Use cl_char4 instead.

**EDIT:** To clarify I will put an example:

**No vectors**

Kernel:

```
__kernel foo(__global char * a, __global char * b){
     b = a;
}
```

Host side:

```
... 
clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, size * cl_char, NULL, NULL);
...
... 
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, size, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
...
```

**Vectors**

Kernel:

```
__kernel foo(__global char4 * a, __global char4 * b){
     b = -a;
}
```

Host side:

```
... 
clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, (size/4+1) * cl_char4, NULL, NULL);
...
... 
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, (size/4+1), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
...
```

Comment: Yep. That's what I meant by that question. If I have char a[1001] in my host and I pass it to my device through a buffer seen in the kernel as of type char4, I guess I will have 251 elements with the last one containing 3 elements to not use.  But is it done automatically by the GPU ? Does OpenCL chose the right global work space ?

Comment: If you have a char of 1001 elements, you should manually map this memory to a char4[251] array, and pass it to the GPU. Then launch a 251 global size kernel. If your operation is element wise in a char level, then simply process and discard the last 3 results produced by your kernel. If not, then you need aditional logic or processing for this last set of only one element.

Comment: Ok ! that's what I thought, but I wanted confirmation as I wasnt sure about it. Thanks !